# Get struct device pointer for this module?

Tags: kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

Is there a way to get pointer to "struct device" for current module in kernel driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Linux Device Driver Model (LDDM), the `probe` method of the kernel driver is called with the first argument as the device. But the type of this first parameter depends on the device class your driver is written for.

For e.g, a UART platform device driver would have, `int (*probe)(struct platform_device *);`.

So the first parameter `platform_device` is a wrapper around the LDDM's standard `struct device` structure which will point to the current device detected by the underlying hardware.

If your kernel module driver supports multiple devices, then you may want to maintain a linked list of all the `struct device` structures or pointers to these structures in a global driver private variable (declared as static to protect other kernel driver modules accessing this linked list and corrupting your device operation).

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no generalized concept of a "current device" in a module. A module is simply a way of dynamically adding code to the kernel. It doesn't necessarily contain (only) a single device driver, or even a device driver at all -- though that is its most common function.

You are free to declare a global variable of your own that points to a struct device of your choosing.

Comment: No global variables, please!